# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'BatchDataset' when data augmenting using fit_generator()

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am having troubles with applying Data Augmentation when training the model. Specifically about the use of the **fit_generator()** method.

I have originally run my model succesfully without augmentation using the **fit()** method, however according to [others](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/12/24/how-to-use-keras-fit-and-fit_generator-a-hands-on-tutorial/) it is recomended to use **fit_generator()**. It seems like both methods need the same input when it comes to images and labels, but I am getting the following **ERROR** when running the code below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_35/139227558.py in <module>
    105 
    106 # train the network
--> 107 model.fit_generator(aug.flow(train_ds,  batch_size=batch_size),
    108         validation_data=val_ds, steps_per_epoch=len(train_ds[0]) // batch_size,
    109     epochs=epochs)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py in flow(self, x, y, batch_size, shuffle, sample_weight, seed, save_to_dir, save_prefix, save_format, subset)
    894         save_prefix=save_prefix,
    895         save_format=save_format,
--> 896         subset=subset)
    897 
    898   def flow_from_directory(self,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py in __init__(self, x, y, image_data_generator, batch_size, shuffle, sample_weight, seed, data_format, save_to_dir, save_prefix, save_format, subset, dtype)
    472         save_format=save_format,
    473         subset=subset,
--> 474         **kwargs)
    475 
    476 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/numpy_array_iterator.py in __init__(self, x, y, image_data_generator, batch_size, shuffle, sample_weight, seed, data_format, save_to_dir, save_prefix, save_format, subset, dtype)
    119                     y = y[split_idx:]
    120 
--> 121         self.x = np.asarray(x, dtype=self.dtype)
    122         self.x_misc = x_misc
    123         if self.x.ndim != 4:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     81 
     82     """
---> 83     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     84 
     85 

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'BatchDataset'
```

I have completed google in trying to fix the **TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'BatchDataset'** error, but to no avail. Does anyone have suggestions as to move forward?

```
import pathlib
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set data directory
data_dir = pathlib.Path("../input/validatedweaponsv6/images/")

# Set image size
img_height = 120
img_width = 120

# Hyperparameters
batch_size = 128
epochs = 50
learning_rate = 0.001

# Create the training dataset
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    label_mode='categorical',
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    shuffle=True,
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size)

# Create the validation dataset
val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    label_mode='categorical',
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
    shuffle=True,
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size)

# Create sequential model
model = Sequential([

    # Preprocessing
    layers.Rescaling(1./127.5, offset=-1,
                     input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)),

    # Encoder
    layers.Conv2D(8, 3, activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
    # layers.Conv2D(2, 3, activation='relu'), ???
    layers.Flatten(),

    # Decoder
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')
])

# Print the model to see the different output shapes
print(model.summary())

# Compile model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=learning_rate), metrics=['accuracy'])

# construct the training image generator for data augmentation
aug = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=20, zoom_range=0.15,
    width_shift_range=0.2, height_shift_range=0.2, shear_range=0.15,
    horizontal_flip=True, fill_mode="nearest")

# train the network
model.fit_generator(aug.flow(train_ds,  batch_size=batch_size),
validation_data=val_ds, steps_per_epoch=len(train_ds[0]) // batch_size,
epochs=epochs)

# Print scores
score = model.evaluate(train_ds, verbose=0)
print('Validation loss:', score[0])
print('Validation accuracy:', score[1])

# Show loss and accuracy models
show_history(history)
```

Thank you for looking at my post! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the article you referred to is 3 years old and is a bit outdated. Starting from tensorflow 2.1.0, the  **.fit** method accepts generators too, and **currently it fully replaced .fit_generator**. I suggest you to update your tensorflow if possible.

Second, the error seems to be not in the fit_generator method, but in the way you define the datasets. They just first called in fit_generator, and that's why the error message trace you back there.

As of the error itself, I don't understand the part of nesting the generators, and I think it can cause problems here. You're trying to pass batched dataset gotten from **tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory** to another generator, which seems to be impossible.

If I understood correctly, you have only one label on each image, and images of each class are stored in separate folders, so I suggest you to use the **flow_from_directory** method of [tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) directly. This generator will both read and augment the images, so you can drop the tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory part.

To use this generator, you need to have images in the form:

- root_directory

  - class1 folder
  - class2 folder
  - etc

and your code will be something like this:

```
gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator( #desired augmentation, ...) 
train_generator = gen.flow_from_directory(directory = root_directory,
target_size=(256, 256), classes= *list of class names*,
class_mode='categorical', batch_size=32, shuffle=True, ...)
model.fit(train_generator, ...)
```

You can pass "validation_split" argument too to get separate datasets for training and validation. Read more about the ImageDataGenerator and flow_from_directory method [in the official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory).